# MigraDoc PDFSharp Table overflow text

Tags: overflow, pdfsharp, migradoc

I am creating a big table with MigraDoc.

I have two issues I don't know how to solve exactly:

1. If the content (Paragraph) of a cell is too long it breaks and I got 2 lines in my cell. I don't want this behavior. I want that the text which does not fit in the first line of the cell is hidden.
2. If a word is too long I want also that the characters which are outside of the cell are hidden. Now they are displayed in the next cell :/ and are overlapping with the content of the next cell...

Do you know how to fix this issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is by design.

Use MeasureString to measure your text before you add it and truncate at the correct place (maybe adding "..." if you want).

See also:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=6158#p6158

Comment: thx - the method in your postet link is a nice snippet. Only had to change a few things.